# Proving a statement using integral form of Taylor remainder

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

The objective is to prove that $\ln(1+x) = T(x)$ for $x \in (-1,1]$, and the way I thought of doing this is to show:

For $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$, that $\lim_{n\to \infty}R_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^{x}f^{(n+1)}(t)\cdot \frac{(t-x)^n}{n!}dt = 0 $ when $x \in (-1,1]$

Doing this and setting a = 0 as usual, I end up obtaining $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{x} \frac{(t-x)^n}{(t+1)^{n+1}}dt = 0$, which I cannot prove. How do I prove it, and if I did something wrong to get to this point, what is my mistake?

Comment: Use the ratio test to test for convergence.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about the ratio test

Comment: You are very welcome :) I don't know how to use it myself, I haven't yet learnt about it, but I've heard of it. Glad to help!

Comment: Sorry, I realized after looking at ratio test again that it applies to infinite series only, and as the integral is now, it cannot be compared immediately to an infinite series so it doesn't work, at least on the surface

Comment: Why must you integrate it?

Comment: I am not saying to integrate, but to bound this integral by an infinite series so that I can apply ratio test as you said on that series. But even so, now that I think about it, ratio test only says that the series converges and not necessarily converge to 0. So I believe it is necessary to either compute the integral or to bound it by something that converges to 0.

Answer (score 0):

We know the general term of the Taylor series expansion of $\ln{x+1}=a_r=(-1)^{r+1} \frac{x^r}{r} $.
Using the ratio test to test for convergence, ie when $$\lim _{r\to \infty}\lvert \frac{a_{r+1}}{a_r}\rvert<1$$
$$\lim _{r\to \infty}\lvert \frac{a_{r+1}}{a_r}\rvert=\lim _{r\to \infty}\lvert \frac{(-1)^{r+2} \frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}}{(-1)^{r+1} \frac{x^r}{r}}\rvert=\lim _{r\to \infty}\lvert \frac{ {\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}}}{ {\frac{x^r}{r}}}\rvert=\lim _{r\to \infty}\lvert\frac{xr}{r+1}\rvert=\lim _{r\to \infty}\lvert\frac{x}{1+\frac{1}{r}}\rvert=\lvert x\rvert$$
So, the expansion converges if $-1<x<1$ as required.
Hope that helped!

Comment: Hello, I am sorry but this only answers part of the question (that it converges) and does not show that it converges to 0, which is what I ultimately need to show. Further, showing that when n->infinity, the nth term of the Taylor polynomial of ln(1+x) converges to some value does not mean the taylor polynomial itself also converges to some value.